Sheets countifs function returning 0 value
I'm trying to work on a google sheets page and count all specific values in a column that are either a 1 or 2 value. I'm basically condensing a survey with a 1-10 range of agreement with questions down to 1-5, "strongly disagree", "mildly disagree", et cetera to rotate those answers to a pivot table and make some pie charts representing the different questions answers.
I'm trying to use the countifs function of "=countifs(B2:B154,"=1",B2:B154,"=2")" but that just keeps returning a value of 0 when there are clearly 1s or 2s as answers. What am I doing wrong, is there a different function I should be using? I'm very new to learning how to use the program.

COUNTIFS uses AND. If you want OR logical expression to be used you can use two COUNTIF (without the s)
=COUNTIF(B2:B154, "=1") + COUNTIF(B2:B154, "=2")


You may try:
=counta(ifna(filter(B2:B154,xmatch(B2:B154,{1,2}))))

OR
=countif(index(regexmatch(B2:B154&"","^(1|2)$")),true)


The syntax you're using for =COUNTIFS() is checking to see if the value is 1 and then checking the same value to see if it's also 2.
Try this
=COUNTIF(B2:B,"1")+COUNTIF(B2:B,"2")


Yup, worked perfectly lol. Didn't know how to stack multiple functions into the same cell, just a + sign between them. Thanks so much!
